# Dask Updating column similar to sql case

Tags: python, dataframe, dask

I have a dask dataframe with a column "is_internal" of type int64.  I want to update this similar to the SQL case statement:

```
 CASE WHEN ltrim(rtrim(is_internal)) = '1' then 'Internal' else 'External' END as type
```

importing the data as:

```
import pandas as pd 
import dask.dataframe as dd
import time
t=time.process_time()
df_train = dd.read_csv(r"C:\test.bcp", sep='\t', sample=25000000)
```

Normally in pandas, I would do something similar to this but this is using a lot of space, which I'm limited on.

```
df_train.loc[df_train['is_internal'] == 1, 'type'] = 'internal'
df_train.loc[df_train['is_internal'] == 0, 'type'] = 'external'
```

What is the best method, that's not going to use a lot of space/memory with dask?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not mutate Dask objects. You can achieve what you want using the [`.where`](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.DataFrame.where) method. Unfortunately, many find its formulation confusing; but in many cases where you would like to directly use a pandas way to proceed, you can wrap your code with `map_partition`:

```
def simple_where(df):
    df.loc[df['is_internal'] == 1, 'type'] = 'internal'
    df.loc[df['is_internal'] == 0, 'type'] = 'external'
    return df

df_out = df_train.map_partitions(simple_where)
```

Comment: i'm getting the error AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'map_partitions'

Comment: Amended the question to show how I'm importing the data. I can't see why map_partitions is not available.

Comment: `df_train=df_train.compute()` - you just loaded everything into a pandas dataframe, which we thought you didn't have the memory to be able to do.

Comment: Just figured that out. I don't on the machine the script will need to run on, i'm working on my desktop.